# breadcrumb like steps navigation

Tags: php, navigation, breadcrumbs

I have a little thing I can't figure out.

I have a page where there are 6 steps. 
How can I make a breadcrumb like navigation where the next steps are inactive and all the previous steps are active?

Ie.

Step 1 > Step 2 > Step 3 > Step 4 > Step 5 > Step 6

Will look like this when I am at step 4

**Step 1** > **Step 2** > **Step 3** > **Step 4** > Step 5 > Step 6

And those active steps will have a parameter in the url pointing back to that step-page.

I.e. the page parameter for step 1 is page=intro

Hope someone can help?

------- SOLUTION -------

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['page'][] = $_GET["page"];

$steps = array(
    "selecthouse" => "Vælg hustype og tagform",
    "selectrooftile" => "Vælg tagsten",
    "angleinput" => "Tagvinkel",
    "rfinish" => "Tag-detaljer",
    "inputdims" => "Indsæt mål",
    "matliste" => "Materiale-liste",
    );

foreach($steps as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($key, $_SESSION['page'])) {       
        echo '<a href="?page='.$key.'">'. $value .'</a></b> >';
    } else {
        echo $value ." > ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, `in_array` comes to mind; checking if link is present in array, if yes apply class and link, else keep it as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, the best really depends on the rest of your code.

My personal preference for linear navigation like this is to store pages the user visits in an array in a session, e.g.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['pages'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

Then all you need to do is put an if in array around each item in the "breadcrumbs", e.g. something like

```
<?php
  if (in_array('/step1.php',$_SESSION['pages'])) {
    ?>
    <a href="/step1.php">Step 1</a>
    <?php
  } else {
    ?>
    Step 1
    <?php
  }
?>
```

EDIT

From your newly posted code, there is a closing `</b>` but no opening tag.

As for unsetting to revert back to a step, you'd be best to do something like this:

```
<?php
  $stepskeys = array_keys($steps);
  $_SESSION['pages'] = array(
    0 => $stepskeys[1],
    1 => $stepskeys[2],
    2 => $stepskeys[3]
  );
?>
```

That would reset the array back to step 3.

Comment: I have edited my question based on your answer! Seems to work!  Thank you! 
A follow up question! 

Can I unset some of the keys when lets say I am at step 6 and moves back to step 3. Then step 4, 5, and 6 will be inactive again.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the missing opening tag :)

I have accepted your answer!